# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 - while parsing JSON string data from file into the web server

Tags: node.js, file, express, input, stream

I have written Json data into the file using `JSON.stringify(data)`.
but, when I read from the file using `JSON.parse(data)`, I get an error Unexpected token u in `JSON at position 0` . It prints `Undefined` when I print `data`

```
function read(req, res) {

    reader.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response += chunk;
    });
    reader.on('end', function () {
        console.log(response);
    })
    reader.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    });

}

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
})


app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
    read(req, res);
    console.log(response);
    res.end(JSON.parse(response)); // Here is the error - reading from file
})
```

---

Contents in the file - `outputs.txt`

### `{"first_name":"Kumar","last_name":"Roul"}`

Code to route from web to file -

```
function write(req, res) {
    response = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name

    };
    writer.write(JSON.stringify(response));
}
app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    write(req, res);
    console.log(response);
    res.end('Successfully written to file');
})
```

Comment: put `JSON.parse` in try catch block, and you are parsing whole response, just parse the needed object or array, tour file from the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to parse the file before you've finished reading it. Since reading the contents happens asynchronously, execution continues. This means `response` is `undefined` at the time you call `JSON.parse`, which requires a string and therefore throws an exception since it's not getting one.

Your `read` function needs to signal when it has finished reading, either by invoking a callback (making the signature `read(req, res, callback)`) or returning a promise. Then your route should do any processing of the file contents in the callback or the promise's `.then()`.

Comment: Hi , yes asynchronous method worked. I am adding screenshot https://ibb.co/nLyR5a , [url=https://ibb.co/nLyR5a][img]https://image.ibb.co/np7ayv/read.png[/img][/url]